# adding minus icon at the end of sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to add minus icon at the end of sortable item, but i am not able to do this, kindly help me in that concern. I am using jqueryui for that.

Thanks,

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You may want to specify what library you are using. Prototype?

Comment: "Sortable" is a very generic term. If you are using a JavaScript library of some sort, you need to give some other details about it (such as its home page).

Comment: the question is tagged jquery, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Is the syntax for appending. Set any HTML you want. So to do this..

```
$('#sortable li').each(function(index) {
$(this).append('any html you want');
});
```

Try that.

Documentation for the each() function: http://api.jquery.com/each/
Documentation for the append() function: http://api.jquery.com/append/